# Searching an Encrypted Database

Tags: mysql, database, encryption

I have a MySQL database table that contains an amount of encrypted data (different subsets encrypted with different keys) that needs to be searchable. If the user is authenticated and has access granted to a certain subset (and therefore has the key for the encrypted data), how can they search through the table's subset? i.e. Not only WHERE `EncryptedKey =`, but also `EncryptedData LIKE` and other Conditions?

The data is stored in the format:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| DataID | SubsetID | EncryptedKey | EncryptedData | EncryptedAttr |
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1      | 1        | xxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2      | 1        | xxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 3      | 1        | xxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 4      | 2        | xxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+--------+----------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I haven't decided on a cryptography suite yet, and I was thinking of a native one to the database server.

Comment: please, which process/program/action encrypts the data?

Comment: Not sure, but I was thinking of using the internal MySQL aes_encrypt as the actual encrypting process, before that, the data will be fed into it normally. 

If I use aes_decrypt in the columns request for the encrypted columns, how processor intensive would that be, and how would the time increase?

Comment: What advantage do you hope to gain from this encryption?

Comment: @markus-tharkun not letting any access to the data, even if someone manages to get into the database directly

Comment: how did you solved it @topherg

Comment: @divyanayanawasthi I did not. Closest I had was to just encrypt blobs of data, then to send parts of it back, dependent upon what the client asked for, then the client-side app decrypt it as necessary. Only problem is, if the client losses their keys, then there is no recovery

Comment: topherg you can also use some hashing algos (one way hash functions to encrypt the data) and search as well . I used one way hash to search data and also encryption  using AWS KMS key .